# how to get Publish info of a page for a particular version?

Tags: 2011, core-service

I am trying to get the publish info of a page for a particular version. I am trying something like below. I am passing the tcmId of the page fro a particular version. The Publish info is same(latest info) for all version.

```
 var pageObject = client.Read("tcm:10-2676-64-v10", null) as PageData;
    var pageObject1 = client.Read("tcm:10-2676-64-v99", null) as PageData;


    if (pageObject != null)
    {
        var pubInfo = client.GetListPublishInfo(pageObject.Id);
    }
    if (pageObject1 != null)
    {

        var pubInfo1 = client.GetListPublishInfo(pageObject1.Id);
    }
```

Is there a way to get the publish info for a particular version of a page ?

Comment: I've outlined design considerations for this type of [published version requirement in this question](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/1881/46). Don't forget item rollbacks and content porter scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. Tridion does not keep version-specific PublishInfo. It relates to the object, not to a specific version.

You would have to add this info yourself - for instance with ApplicationData and a custom event handler - if you need to track it.